# Unable to render Bullet in Thunderhead

Tags: xsl-fo

I am trying to create a document in thunderhead (Business Content studio) and trying to render the document as a AFP file. but the rendering process is getting error-ed out , If we remove the bullet it is getting rendered. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the XSL-FO that causes the error plus the error message.

Comment: Hi Tony, thanks for looking in to it. I'm unable to view any error message, I can only the see the  message  in Job manager console that -  "Failed to render document" . But once I remove the bullet it is rendered properly not only bullet Tick mark is also creating issue. I'm new into thunderhead tool, and I'm not sure where I can see the error message. Please do help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the FOP Renderer and single-byte AFP fonts, the problem is that the standard ASCII bullet character is extended--its code point is higher than 255, which means it requires more than a byte to represent it. You'll need to set your bullets in an alternate font (or the same font with a codepage that shifts the first 255 codepoints to a different range of glyphs). I believe a lowercase "u" in Zapf Dingbats works quite well, and I believe Zapf Dingbats is embedded in the renderer.